# Matching input tag with Cucumber/Webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

I'm learning Cucumber, but I can't make a step for just matching input tags.

What I have in the view is

```
<input type="submit" value="Press!" />
```

And what I tried in Cucumber are

```
Then the "input" field should contain "Press!"
Then the "type" field should contain "submit"
```

I just wanna confirm the existence for the input tags with certain values. No interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're also explicitly supported in webrat.  Even if you can't find the built-in support in cucumber, you can always just drop into your own step definitions.

source:  http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/webrat/

```
== Assertions

   # check for text in the body of html tags
   # can be a string or regexp
  assert_contain("BURNINATOR")
  assert_contain(/trogdor/i)
  assert_not_contain("peasants")

  # check for a css3 selector
  assert_have_selector 'div.pagination'
  assert_have_no_selector 'form input#name'


== Matchers

  # check for text in the body of html tags
  # can be a string or regexp
  # Matchers are verbs used with auxillary verbs should, should_not, etc.
  response.should contain("BURNINATOR")
  response.should contain(/trogdor/i)
  response.should_not contain("peasants")

  # check for a css3 selector
  response.should have_selector('div.pagination')
  response.should_not have_selector('form input#name')
```

Comment: I found this by searching for 'trogdor'. Strong bad on, dude!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`Then I should see "Press!" within "input[type=\"submit\"]"`

Comment: Thanks. To me it's very strange that none of the frameworks have the easy ways to check the existence for form elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
response.should have_xpath("//input[@value='Press!']")
```

or

```
response.should have_selector("input", :type => "submit", :value => "Press!")
```